# Geckodriver - unable to click the element

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

i am trying to automate logout functionality for - https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/
I could log out using chrome and edge but firefox is not clicking the element and selecting logout.

new WebDriverWait(cdriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id="welcome"]"))).click();

new WebDriverWait(cdriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),"Logout")]"))).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using linktext

```
new WebDriverWait(cdriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Logout"))).click();
```

If it is still not working try clikcking using javascript

Comment: Javascript solution worked.. Thank you :-)